# MMYOLO not showing validation metrics during training

Tags: validation, yolo

I am investigating MMYOLO and tried to train it on CrowdHuman dataset. I did everything as was explained in [here](https://mmyolo.readthedocs.io/en/latest/get_started/15_minutes_object_detection.html#training) but didn't get the validation results as it was mentioned in the tutorial:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xrhhd.png)

> Maybe that is a bug or someone has run into something like that?

I was trying to change **yolov5_s-v61_fast_8xb16-300e_crowdhuman.py** file, mostly validation parameters but still got nothing.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.